# When to use __declspec(dllexport) in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, dllexport

I am making this DLL project and do not include any of compiler-specific macros.

The importer(.exe) files compiles clean and no error generated after importing methods in my DLL file. They are on different projects but same solution.

Do I mess up things here because of not using any of those calling convention?

My DLL files are in a namespace and implemented in OOP manner.

But sometimes or most of the times, the .lib does not generated so I got to switch the setting of my DLL to LIB and copy the generated .lib file and turn it back again to DLL file again.

And I don't even know if the library I am using is a .dll or .lib file.

Someone explains it to me clearly?

**EDIT**

I will add some situations where I am really confuse on when to use it.

suppose to be I have these:

```
namespace
{

    class Base abstract
    {

    public:
        Base()
        {
            //initialize base components
        }
        virtual void func() = 0;

    public:

        //interface
    };

    class Derive : public Base
    {

    public:
        Derive();
        void func() override;

    private:

        //interface

    };

}
```

Should I use `declspec(dllexport)` here:

- The `constructors` (such as `Base()` and `Derive()`) ?
- `virtual` functions? where will I put it? in the derive or in the base? or both?
- public variables? (horrible!)

I see on other header files, they add `extern` into it. Do I need it here?

This will ruin all of my code syntaxes

answers please....

Comment: I really hate those who just view this post and thinking like: "I don't know this stuff" -> [better to down vote] without living any comments. just....

Comment: You're assuming a lot by thinking that the only reason to downvote is not knowing what `dllexport` is... ;-]

Comment: no I really mean about that is, they're just too lazy to read all the details I'm saying here. I just misexpress what I'm trying to say

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as if you are linking in your library files that should be in the dll. So you are not using the dll's at all. Everything is going into the exe file.

Microsoft require the `__declspec(dllexport)` in the dll and `__declspec(dllimport`) in the exe. It gets complicated so there are macros to sort it out.

```
CLASS_DECLSPEC
```

The complier then sorts out which one of the `__declspec`'s to use.

See:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy(v=vs.80).aspx