# Do I really need __declspec(dllexport) when cross-compiling a DLL with MinGW and wclang?

Tags: c++, dll, mingw

There are similar questions here but they don't quite answer my question:

- [When to use __declspec(dllexport) in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311577/when-to-use-declspecdllexport-in-c)
- [Why do I need __declspec(dllexport) to make some functions accessible from ctypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276362/why-do-i-need-declspecdllexport-to-make-some-functions-accessible-from-ctype)

**When I cross-compile a DLL from Mac OS X using MinGW and [wclang](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/wclang), why does my DLL work fine without using `__declspec`?**

The [MinGW DLL sample docs](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll), and every reference I see to doing this, say to use `__declspec(dllexport)` before function declarations. Yet *none* of the code in my 9,000-line library uses it, and the DLL works great!

For example, here's a contrived example library built in the same way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {

int hello(const char* name) {
  printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
  return 0;
}

}
```

Compiled with this on Mac OS X 10.10.3:

```
w32-clang++ test.cpp -shared -o test.dll
```

Produces a fine-looking DLL:

[image]

And my Windows application:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef int(*hellofn)(const char*);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  DWORD err;

  HINSTANCE dll = LoadLibrary(L"E:\\test.dll");
  if (!dll) {
    err = GetLastError();
    std::cout << "Can't load library: " << err << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  hellofn hello = (hellofn)GetProcAddress(dll, "hello");
  if (!hello) {
    err = GetLastError();
    std::cout << "Could not load the function: " << err << std::endl;
    return 2;
  }

  int ret = hello("nerd");
  std::cout << "hello() returned " << ret << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Works great:

[image]

Am I shooting myself in the foot somehow, or is there some magic that I'm not seeing? I'm thinking that wclang (MinGW+clang) knows to use `__stdcall` automatically somehow and doesn't mangle the function names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not **need** `__declspec(dllexport)`, when building a DLL with MinGW; (in fact, I frequently omit it myself). The caveat is that, if just one symbol to be included in the DLL is so decorated, then all others you wish to have exported **must** be likewise decorated, (unless you pass the `--export-all-symbols` option to the linker when you build the DLL).

If you include **only undecorated** symbols, then all global symbols will be exported, just as if `--export-all-symbols` were specified by default.

However, this has nothing whatsoever to do with `__stdcall` vs. `__cdecl` calling conventions, or name mangling; it is solely a determinant of the visibility of symbols in the DLL's export table. If you don't declare your functions to be `__stdcall` or `__cdecl`, then they will be `__cdecl` by default; that's no problem, provided both providing DLL and caller agree on that convention.  Similarly, if both agree on any name mangling convention, (which normally means that, in the case of C++ in particular, they both used the same compiler at build time), then there will be no linking problems.

Comment: Tremendous explanation. Thank you!